# In XPages mobile app, how to avoid appending resetContent=false/true after pressing Done?

Tags: xpages, mobile-controls

I've a mobile page developed with ExtLib mobile controls:
http://hostname/mydb.nsf/MobileTest.xsp

The page consists of two appPages (i.e. a "mainPage" appPage & a "subPage" appPage).

Click on an entry in the mainPage will move to the subPage. Click on the "Done" button in the subPage will move back to the mainPage. After moving back to the mainPage, the resulting URL will automatically change to: http://hostname/mydb.nsf/MobileTest.xsp#mainPage&resetContent=false

When this happened, if I press the browser's refresh button on my iPhone, instead of showing the mainPage, a grey blank page will be displayed. Then, if I manually remove &resetContent=false from the URL and press the refresh button again, the mainPage will be displayed properly.

So, is there any way to suppress appending &resetContent=false (or true) after clicking on a Done button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the cause of this and have put a fix into the ExtLib, it will be in the next release. I don't know when that will be at the minute but will update when I know

Comment: Yes, the reload issue has been fixed in ExtLib 853.20120605-0921. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See answer:

http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/response.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=0B41430C59FA242C862579D50034D72A